# DWR Cookie (DWRSESSIONID) and its use

Tags: cookies, session-state, session-cookies, dwr, httpsession

Was wondering what is the use of `DWRSESSIONID` that is generated by `DWR` and sent to the browser? Is it associated with HTTPSession ? Don't see any practical reasons to create this cookie, when `JSESSIONID` is used to maintain state.

Answer (score 3):

The DWRSESSIONID cookie was added in DWR 3.0 to protect against [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).  It is set when a call is first made by the server-side DWR class `Batch.java`.  On subsequent calls, it is used by `BaseDwrpHandler.java` to check for a CSRF attack.  It is available even if there is no HttpSession, hence no JSESSIONID.  Explained by [Mike Wilson on the DWR-Users mailing list](http://dwr.2114559.n2.nabble.com/CSRF-Protection-Am-I-doing-something-wrong-or-is-DWR-easy-to-attack-td7054463.html):

> In the DWR 3.0 model we create our own session cookie ("DWRSESSIONID")
>   so there will always be a session cookie to base the CSRF check off,
>   even if the application doesn't use the HttpSession.